# Php Laravel get relation inside relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem, I am trying to retrieve orders with products from my database. The idea is that you have an order with products in it and a product can have options with different options. For example a big mac menu has different options, such as size with three different options. This is what I have now:

OrderModel:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'orders';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function table()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Table::class);
    }

    public function branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Branch::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity');
    }


}
```

OrderProduct:

```
class OrderProduct extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $incrementing = true;
    protected $table = 'order_product';

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderProductOptions::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

OrderProductOptions:

```
class OrderProductOptions extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $incrementing = true;
    protected $table = 'order_product_options';

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderProductsOptionsOptions::class);
    }
}
```

OrderProductsOptionsOptions:

```
class OrderProductsOptionsOptions extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'order_products_options_options';

    public function Option()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OrderProductOptions::class);
    }

}
```

[image]

When I want to pick up an order with products and selected options like this:

```
$newOrder = Order::with('products.options')->findOrFail($order->id);
```

I get all the options that the product has, how do I get only the selected ones that belong to the order?

Answer (score 1):

see [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structurehttps://) document , you must define foringPivotKey and relatedPivot key like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
```